# Pass term_id value in wp_insert_term() function

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal

I wanted to pass custom term_id in wp_insert_term() function in wordpress

Currently it accepts:

```
wp_insert_term( string $term, string $taxonomy, array|string $args = array() )
```

The reason is simple, i want to import thousands of terms from Drupal and going to use this function to do it, and wanted to keep the term_id same as Drupal tid.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @zidniryi Update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out this, you can pass term_id while creating terms in custom code by wp->insert:

```
// Insert term and pass term_id
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'terms', array(
  'term_id' => 12345,
  'name' => "Term Name Here",
  'slug' => "term-slug-here"
));

//insert to term_taxonomy
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'term_taxonomy',array(
  'term_taxonomy_id' => 12345,
  'term_id' => 12345,
  'taxonomy' => 'post',
  'parent' => 0
));
```

You can't directly pass wp_insert_term() function, you have to use the above code to do it.